# Labels displaying with multiple bounding rectangles

Tags: qgis, labeling, rendering, debugging

While setting up labeling of a line (road) layer, the labels started displaying with multiple bounding rectangles along with the text.

After trying many different labeling configurations without getting only text to display, I was able to work around by abandoning the problem project and starting over with a new project, same data, same label configuration, and they started displaying correctly.  So the problem seems to be with the project itself.

Easier to show than describe.
Problem project -

[image: Problem labels]

Correct rendering -

[image]

Looks to me like the boxes are the tracks of the placement iterations of the labeling engine.  Maybe I have bumbled into some debugging setting?

Using QGIS 2.18.16 running in Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Solved by Steven Kay.  Operator error - debugging setting set.  Added "debugging" tag to question to facilitate others finding this.

Comment: That's a fun graphic effect. Does it persist when printing from the print composer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're right, it is a debugging setting. It can be handy for troubleshooting labeling issues.

It's next to the pull-down for the labeling list so you may have activated it by mistake. In my version, you have to specifically check on "show candidates" to enable this; perhaps in your version this is checked by default, so dismissing the dialog with **OK** enables the outlines..?

The icon to activate/deactivate is tucked away in the top-right corner of the layer properties > label dialog, shown circled below.

[image]

Comment: That was exactly the situation.  I had inadvertently set "Show candidates" in the dialog.  Reset to defaults and we are back in business.  Thanks so much for your prompt reply.