# Feature blending showing bounding box?

Tags: qgis, symbology

I am experiencing a strange behavior when symbolizing a point layer using any kind of [Feature Blending](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html?highlight=blending#blending-modes).

I am currently using QGIS 2.18.16 but I have seen this in previous versions (edit: tried now in QGIS 3.0.0 and the problem is still there). What happens is when some points are in the same exact coordinate, the feature blending shows the bounding box of the circle representing the point.

[image]

Is there any way to avoid this? Has anyone detected this behavior?
I guess this is a general bug but maybe is something related to our video card.

**Edit:** Stranger things even stranger. If I set all symbol colors to transparent, I can get a map of just the bounding boxes of the overlapping points.

[image]
[image]

Taking a closer look at the screen, the bounding box appears always but you can notice it better when the points overlap since it is almost transparent.

The composer manager has a different behavior. It doesn't show the bounding boxes and when exporting the map the bounding box is not there.
We have tried this in three computers and the result is the same.

Comment: Odd. I can't reproduce with 2.18.16 and a HD520 graphics card. Can you reproduce after restarting QGIS? A fresh project?

Comment: What are you using to create that circle symbol. An Image?

Comment: @mixedbredie Yes, it happens all the time. We are using NVIDIA Quadro K600

Comment: @AlexandreNeto No, a shapefile point layer

Comment: I mean, how is that symbol created? Circles!? Or svg?

Comment: @AlexandreNeto Single symbol > Marker > Simple marker, size: 30 (in map units meters). The feature blending mode is "Multiply" but it happens with any feature blending mode. No svg

Comment: Size and color of the marker  outline?

Comment: @AlexandreNeto No Pen, if I add any pen, the bounding box increases its size

Comment: Interesting. It means the problem is there. Fiddle around with the outline color (even with no pen or 0 width) try using a totally transparent color.

Comment: Ok, I have tried all combinations. Changing the size of outline changes the size of the bounding box even if I set it to "No Pen". The color has no effect on the bounding: same color, different, transparent, black, white...The style, units and join style have no effect either.

Comment: Did you tried the approach with ellipse marker with symbol height and width with same values ( creating a circle) ?

Comment: @LaughU Good! Using a circular ellipse also solves the problem.

Comment: Sounds similar to the issue experienced in this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/269760/labels-displaying-with-multiple-bounding-rectangles/269761#269761

Answer (score 6, accepted):

as discussed in the comments and just adding it for compilation:

Another hack might be to use ellipse markers with the same value for symbol height and symbol width, which consequently create a circle and thus might be more performant than using a geometry generator for large point clouds.

Comment: Yes, it is definitively faster in performance!

Comment: glad I could help :)

Comment: Still, the issue you faced sounds like a bug. You should report the issue.

Answer (score 8):

Well, there is a workaround using the geometry generator.

When representing a buffer of the point layer (buffer( $geometry,15)) instead of a simple marker, the bounding box shadow doesn't appear.

[image]

Still, it is a strange behavior and for the comments it seems not universal at all..